# What is the quickest way to retrieve remote file size from HTTP server that doesn't support HEAD?

Tags: python-2.7, http, pycurl

I am trying to download 1000s of files which may be very large (several GB) from an HTTP site using PycURL.

Everything was going swimmingly until I decided to check for partial downloads, so tried to use info I found on this forum to try to get the Content-Length.  Once I realised it was always returning 179.0, I looked into the response and found that 179.0 seems to be the length of the "Why didn't you check first that what you are doing is supported?" response.

```
>>> c.setopt(c.RANGE, "NULL")
>>> c.setopt(c.HEADER,1)
>>> c.setopt(c.NOBODY,1)
>>> c.perform()
HTTP/1.1 501 Not Implemented
Date: Fri, 14 Aug 2015 02:00:35 GMT
Server: Apache-Coyote/1.1
Pragma: no-cache
DataServiceVersion: 1.0
Content-Type: application/xml
Content-Length: 179
```

Second attempt to get the size, I tried using RANGE.  Range works on the server but running the suggested 0-0 seems to be extremely slow.

```
>>> c.setopt(c.RANGE, "0-0")
>>> c.setopt(c.HEADER,1)
>>> c.setopt(c.NOBODY,0)
>>> c.perform()
HTTP/1.1 206 Partial Content
Date: Fri, 14 Aug 2015 02:05:15 GMT
Server: Apache-Coyote/1.1
Pragma: no-cache
Accept-Ranges: bytes
Content-Disposition: inline; filename="foo.zip"
Content-Range: bytes 0-0/2278939680
```

I don't need to stick with PycURL to find the size but I do need speed.

N.B. I'm using Python 2.7